# Spring Boot will auto configure JPA transaction manager

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am creating Spring Boot application which interact with single DB.I have used `@EnableAutoconfiguration` and `@EnableTransactionManagement` and provided `spring-data-jpa`.

I want to use Hibernate JPA vendor and its dialect. Does spring will auto configure this and JPA transactionmanager or Do I need to manually register these beans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide this minimal jpa configuration in your `application.yml` so that spring could configure hibernate. Please change the property format accordingly if you are using `application.properties` file.

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://<mysql_db_url_here>
        username: <mysql_username>
        password: <mysql_pwd>
        driver-class-name: <db_driver_class> (e.g. com.mysql.jdbc.Driver)

    jpa:
        database-platform: <db_dilect_class> (e.g. org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect)
```